# Problem With Uploading Large Image File to SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, upload, sharepoint-clientobject

so I have a script that essentially iterates through a bunch of delimited text files and uploads the images from said files to a SharePoint site. It works great, expect with one minor problem, I have a couple of images that are >4MB in size and these give me a `(400) Bad Request` error when the script attempts to upload them.

**Code below**:

```
    class spImageUpload()
    {
        private static System.Collections.Generic.List<string> keywords;
        private static NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        private static ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(site name);
        private static Web site = clientContext.Web;
        private static List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        private static FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();

        private static Image image = new Image();
        private static FileIO fo = new FileIO();

        public SharePointAccess()
        {
            sharepointLogin();
            uploadImage();
        }

        private static void updateFields()
        {
            //Loads the site list
            clientContext.Load(list);
            //Creates a ListItemCollection object from list
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            //Loads the listItems
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            //Executes the previous queries on the server
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //For each listItem...
            foreach (var listItem in listItems)
            {
                //Writes out the item ID and Title
                //Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} Title: {1}", listItem.Id, listItem["Title"]);
                //Loads the files from the listItem
                clientContext.Load(listItem.File);
                //Executes the previous query
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //Writes out the listItem File Name
                //Console.WriteLine("listItem File Name: {0}", listItem.File.Name);

                //Looks for the most recently uploaded file, if found...
                if (listItem.File.Name.Contains(fileName))
                {
                    title = fileName;
                    //Changes the Title field value
                    listItem["Title"] = title;
                    //Changes the Keywords field value using the keywords list
                    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
                    {
                        listItem["Keywords"] += keyword;
                        //Writes out the item ID, Title, and Keywords
                        //Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} Title: {1} Keywords: {2}", listItem.Id, listItem["Title"], listItem["Keywords"]);
                    }
                }
                //Remember changes...
                listItem.Update();
            }
            //Executes the previous query and ensures changes are committed to the server
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        private static void uploadImage()
        {
            try
            {
                fo.loadFile();

                foreach (var img in fo.lImageSet)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Image Name: {0}", img.getName());
                }

                foreach (var img in fo.lImageSet)
                {
                    DateTime start;
                    DateTime end;

                    start = DateTime.Now;
                    //Sets file path equal to the path value stored in the current image of lImageSet
                    filePath = img.getPath();
                    //Writes out to the console indicating what's been stored in filePath
                    Console.WriteLine("Image Path: {0}", filePath);
                    //Reads in the contents of the file
                    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                    //Sets the file name equal to the name value stored in the current image of lImageSet
                    fileName = img.getName() + ".jpeg";
                    //Sets the URL path for the file
                    newFile.Url = fileName;
                    //Creates a List object of type String
                    keywords = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
                    //For each keyword in the current image stored in lImageSet...
                    foreach (var keyword in img.lTags)
                    {
                        //...add that keyword to the newly created list
                        keywords.Add(keyword);
                    }
                    //Uploads the file to the picture library
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                    //Loads uploadFile method
                    clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                    //Executes previous query
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    //Calls the updateFields method to update the associated fields of the most recently uploaded image
                    updateFields();

                    end = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan span = end.Subtract(start);
                    //Writes out to the console to indicate the file has finished being uploaded
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploaded: {0}", fileName + " Done!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed: {0}", span.Seconds + "seconds");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void sharepointLogin()
        {
            try
            {
                //Loads credentials needed for authentication
                clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
                //Loads the site
                clientContext.Load(site);
                //Loads the site list
                clientContext.Load(list);
                //Executes the previous queries on the server
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //Writes out the title of the SharePoint site to the console
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", site.Title);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now, I have to do everything remotely using the client-object model. I can't use SharePoint.Administration to change the max upload size. So does anyone know how, using the client-object model I can get past this problem of not being able to upload files greater than 4MB? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: that limit is a security measure so I would suspect that circumventing this would be like "hacking" your way in if at all possible... even if possible: without changing the limit server-side that wouldn't be anything usable in production code...

Comment: Hmm, so you think the only feasible option is to contact the SharePoint admin to try and change the setting on the server side?

Comment: I may be wrong, but that's how see this...

Comment: As a former SharePoint admin, I can assure you that the only way is for an admin to do it. As mentioned - it's a security "feature."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the WCF limit for the client object model. You need to run this on the server from a SharePoint management shell with admin rights:

```
SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
contentService.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;  // 2GB
contentService.Update();
```

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the SaveBinaryDirect method. The SaveBinaryDirect method use Web Based Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) for uploading and downloading files. Without building your own custom WCF service, WebDAV
is the most efficient way to upload and download files.

```
using (FileStream lp_fs = new FileStream(is_FileToImport, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(lp_context, lp_uri.LocalPath, lp_fs, true);
}
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File lp_newFile = lp_web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(lp_uri.LocalPath);
lp_context.Load(lp_newFile);
lp_context.ExecuteQuery();

//check out to make sure not to create multiple versions
lp_newFile.CheckOut();

ListItem lp_item = lp_newFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["Created"] = info.SourceFile.CreationTime;
listItem["Modified"] = info.SourceFile.LastWriteTime;
listItem.Update();

// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
lp_newFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```